# How do I specify a type argument explicitly when reading an XML file in UWP

Tags: c#, xml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on a UWP app where I need to read and write an XML file to the device. It took me a while of searching to find a tutorial that covered the basics well enough for me to "sort of" understand it. This tutorial [Serialize/Deserialize an Object to an XML File (Windows Universal apps 8.1)](http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=624) has a succinct example that according to the comments should work. However I am getting this error when I F5 it ***The type arguments for method  cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.***

The error surfaces on this line

```
Robot robot2 = await XmlIO.XmlRW.ReadObjectFromXmlFileAsync("robbie.xml");
```

The method that it points to is this

```
    public static async Task<T> ReadObjectFromXmlFileAsync<T>(string filename)
    {
        // this reads XML content from a file ("filename") 
        // and returns an object  from the XML
        T objectFromXml = default(T);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        objectFromXml = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        stream.Dispose();
        return objectFromXml;
    }
```

I thought that maybe I needed to change the Task < T > to a Task < string > but I couldn't make that work either. So what do I need to do to specify the type argument explicitly?

Comment: ReadObjectFromXmlFileAsync<Robot>("robbie.xml")

Comment: How large is your XML file?  Not sure why you need asynchronous reads when you are getting the file from a local file system (or small xml).  Why did you choose this approach?  There are many different ways of parsing xml.

Comment: @jdweng The XML file is in export from a SQL server table that is 300 rows / 10 columns wide. I am not sure if the warrants asynchronous reads or not but it was the only tutorial that I could find that walked me though the very basics or reading and writing an XML in a UWP app

Comment: @lonewolf that did solve my problem. If you post that answer I will accept that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can't determine what type T will be. You need to specify it explicitly:

```
Robot robot2 = await XmlIO.XmlRW.ReadObjectFromXmlFileAsync<Robot>("robbie.xml");
```